# Mapbox.js: Accessing data markers created in Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapbox

I used Mapbox Studio to create some projects because my data set was too large to use Mapbox Editor. I loaded my data into a source project and then used that source as a layer in a style project, which I then uploaded to Mapbox [here](https://api.mapbox.com/v4/interwebjill.d3906716/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiaW50ZXJ3ZWJqaWxsIiwiYSI6ImViYTMyNWYzZjhkMWM2ZjJmYzA1NjlmNDE4ZTgyM2NjIn0.k2cbaDYhHOlHmr7n1wPQIg#3/30.36/-170.80).

I used conditional formatting rules in CartoCSS to color-code the data markers based on the "species" represented (the map is created from migration data of large marine animals). I would like to create another map using Mapbox.js that allows me to change the marker color based on whether that species is selected or not, like [this one](http://www.thinkingthroughart.info/species_toggle4.html).

If a species is not selected, the marker should be dull gray in color, if the species is selected, it will be its vibrant color.

My question is: how do I reference those individual species markers that have been cooked as a source project into a layer of the style project in Mapbox Studio? Can I use Mapbox.js to access the CartoCSS or will I need to access some GeoJSON? The data was originally uploaded as csv so I would need to understand the GeoJSON working behind the Mapbox scenes (if that is what is happening).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick background on loading vector tiles using leaflet/mapbox.js might help. You are not actually loading geojson into the browser.  Inspect your map tiles and you'll notice that you are still loading `.pngs`.  So, there is no 'geojson working behind the MapBox scenes', and thus browser-side rendering is not actually possible.

So, your options are:

- load the data on top of the basemap as a geojson and filter/render in the browser.  You mentioned you didn't do this b/c of the size of the data set.  If it's still an issue, you could:

  - convert the points to lines and optionally smooth the geometry
  - load points by species so you are making more requests for smaller amounts of data
- check out [mapbox-gl-js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/) which uses web-gl to render vector tiles in the browser.  There's a little more involved in getting everything up and running, and you style using a json-based language, rather than Carto, which can take some time to learn.

Also see [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103762/guidance-when-to-style-your-features-in-tilemill-vs-leaflet/103784#103784), and search for other posts on client or browser rendering.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but it's "mapbox-gl-js" not "mapbox-gl". (The latter is the previous name of their mobile library I think.)

Comment: @SteveBennett edited